# Different types of Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui, bing-maps

I am currently implementing a Kendo Map Widget using bing maps where i want to display markers.
Therefore every marker needs an array with locations in the form [latitude, longitude].
As long as i am hardcoding these decimal values, everything is displayed correctly, but but when i fetch the coordinates from an external source convert them with parseFloat() and put them inside an array it does not display any markers.

I researched with the browser devtools (Internet Explorer 11) and there the hardcoded version displays

```
 [39.772234,-84.190484]
```

whereas the constructed version shows

```
 [object (init)]
```

and posesses the additional attributes [Methods] and _events.

To my knowledge there is no simple object for Array in Javascript or am i wrong?
What is the difference between these two arrays?

Comment: How exactly do you "put them inside an array"?  What does the code to do that look like?

Comment: The difference you're seeing in the examples you show is only in how the developer tools are displaying the data. They are both Arrays, which are both objects. Perhaps try `console.dir()` on both to get expandable objects each time.

Comment: I know that both are arrays and i already inspected the expandable objects (this is why i know of their attributes) but they seem to differ in some way because it does not work with the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.
The Problem lies with the kendo datasource which i use to store the markers array. It seems to manipulate the array in some way and make it incompatible with the map control.
When using a global variable everything works just fine.